# Sudden spikes in SQL connections causing timeouts

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database

For the last week I've been experiencing intermittent mini-outages lasting between 1-3 minutes every few hours. We're using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and EF6 on top of Azure SQL for years, and it has served us well. Starting about 10 days ago however, we're seeing these sudden bursts of SQL connections being opened. These sudden bursts of SQL connections are causing timeouts on any new requests, causing our website to be inaccessible. For context: our platform sees about 1.1 million unique visitors every single day and traffic is always very stable and predictable with no sudden bursts, even during the mini outages traffic is perfectly normal.

The exception we get during these bursts is **'
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.'**

We use a combination of StructureMap with Nested Contaienrs to inject our DbContext in controllers and services, and in legacy parts of the codebase we religiously consume our DbContext with usings. We never manually open a connection (so no SqlConnections floating around)

Azure metrics (Succesful connections last 48 hours)

[image]

Azure SQL usage charts (24 hours)

[image]

The spikes here don't align with the outages so don't seem suspicious to us.

These bursts automatically resolve themselves within minutes. If I'm fast enough while our platform alerts notify us, I can confirm using 'exec sp_who' that there are indeed an excessive amount of idle connections (status=sleeping, cmd=AWAITING COMMAND) to our database. We are constantly running on 4 similarly specced VM's, and when this burst happens, the idle connections don't originate from one single machine.

We've been scratching our heads for the last week especially since the way we've been using EF6 and SQL Server has been a very smooth ride for several years. We obviously scoured over every single change we've made to the platform codebase over the last 2 weeks to spot anything that seems suspicious, but sadly that hasn't resulted in anything yet. We're also diligently squashing and tuning all our heavier un-optimized queries in a bid to fix this, but they've been serving the website fine for years and this really only started about 10-12 days ago.

Anyone who can give some insight into what might cause such very sudden bursts; any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: This seems to be network issue. Are you using a retry policy in order to establish the connection?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio We have the following line of code configured in our DbContext. 'SetExecutionStrategy("System.Data.SqlClient", () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy());'

This is supposed to have built-in 5-times retry behavior built-in, as I understand it.

Comment: seems to me you're not closing connections properly

Comment: @JarrichVandeVoorde, maybe you can get more info using https://github.com/amachanic/sp_whoisactive or run sp_blitzfirst to get more insights

Comment: Did you find out what was going on here? We are having a similar issue.

Comment: Same here. We've been in contact with Azure Support but they only tell us to upgrade our SQL service plan, while it has been running fine on the current service plan for two years...

Same spikes happen to us with no real traceable cause.

Comment: Thank you @PrebenHuybrechts 

We did find that at least -some- of those spikes aligned with regular 1-2 minute DDOS attempts from the outside that seemed to instantly saturate our DB connection pool and have better mitigation measures in place now to protect us from those surges.

Comment: @JarrichVandeVoorde How did you find out about the DDoS attacks? Is there a way to check for them (in the Azure Portal)? We're also still looking for the cause on our end and we're drawing a blank for now...

Comment: @Bert you should be able to check for DDoS attacks by looking at your app service metrics on requests. In our case we do not have an increase in the number of requests that correspond to the increase in open connections. Also if you are properly pooling your sql connections even a DDoS attack shouldn't exhaust your sql connections. We still have not found a solution for this.

Comment: @Bert We use regular Azure web app metrics, but we also heavily use Azure Log Analytics. That allowed us to query all requests that happened inside and outside those DDoS periods and revealed very unusual request patterns. (like uncommon, but heavy routes being hammered etc).